# Wrapping JRE with my JAR in one EXE file

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I have read many threads in `stackoverflow` but I didn't get the answer.

I used `JSmooth` and `Launch4j` but what I want exactly is to get a final `.exe` file from my `JAR` application and a `JRE` so that my windows client won't need to install any `JRE` (in another way: to get a portable application with its own `JVM`)

I found that is not possible but why? Does that need the compilation fo the `jre` with my application source?
I hope my question is clear, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean that installs to a single file, or are you happy for a single .exe installer to extract to a separate JRE and your .jar? This is certainly possible, e.g. Oracle and Informix DB tools do that.

Comment: Yeah, I want them in a single executable file

Comment: @RobinGreen sorry the answer is not clear in "possible duplicate answer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the JRE folder and include it as a resource in your .exe file.

At run time, you'll need to extract that resource to the disk, unzip it and then invoke it using ShellExecute to run your .jar file. The size of your executable will probably be quite huge.

This is your only viable solution.. Otherwise, if it is for windows only, why not just write the whole application in C++? Is there a reason why you need your JRE with the application? Why not let the user install their own JVM?

Comment: My application is ready and has been developped using java, and at this moment, it is not compatible with JRE7.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `ShellExecute` in java?